# Вопрос эффективности многопоточности в игре "Арканоид" Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, разработка-игр, 2d, java2d

Итак у меня есть такие классы:

1) **Solution** (Main)
Основной класс с методом main, рисует форму, запускает треды 2), 3), 4)

2) **GamePanel**
тред (по совместительству наследник JPanel), отрисовывает все объекты с частотой 50 fps, т.е. Thread.sleep(20). Проблем с тредом нет.

3) **ThreadKeyLis** 
ловит события клавы, движение/нажатие мышки. Проблем с тредом нет, работает без Thread.sleep(n). 
ЗЫ только может кто подскажет, что можно использовать вместо KeyListener, ибо он очень медленный

4) **ThreadMovingBall**
Проблма в этом треде. Выполняет вычисления, связанные с перемещением мяча, вычислением угла полета, чеком коллизии с кирпичами, стенками, и тележкой. У меня на компе 2 ядра, и в принципе все работает пучком. Но я заметил такой интересный момент на одноядерном динозавре, (который ведь тоже должен тянуть примитивные игры типа арканоида), короче иногда, примерно через 15 секунд после старта игры (т.е. на 15 секунде полета мяча) скорость мяча резко падает, причем раз в 10, и получается такое себе слоу-мо, которое я абсолютно не планировал. Причем слоу-мо проявляется только в полете мяча, тележка как двигалась, так и двигается, т.е проблема с тредом ThreadMovingBall. Слоу-мо пропадает, как только я смещаю фокус с окна игры на другое окно, например консоль. Пока что,у меня есть черновой вариант решения, перенести код из треда мяча в тред ThreadKeyLis, ведь в нем все равно безхозный зацикленный метод run(). Однако это смахивает на костыль, к тому же реализация убивает половину уже написанного кода, а мне совсем лень выполнять механическую работу, моя интуиция подсказывает мне, что должно быть элегантное решение, возможно оно даже не связано с тредами. Ведь минкрафт как то работает с его 3D миром.. Получается, мне нужно решение, которое в фоне будет выполнять точные вычисления с координатами мяча и углом полета, и это не повлияет на остальной процесс, если такое вообще возможно.

5) **GameBar** 
Просто JPanel для отрисовки очков

6) **Brick** 
Кирпич

7) **BrickMap** 
Массив кирпичей

Простите за много текста, мне показалось, что нужно дать более общую картину, чтобы стало понятно в чем проблема. Я бы запихнул код, но его довольно много. Сразу скажу, что гуглить я умею очень хорошо, просто даже не представляю, как в этом случае сформулировать вопрос и где копать. Заранее извиняюсь, если потратил чье-то время. Игру делаю с целью получше разобраться в многопоточности, 2D графике, Swing

Comment: Вы написали что тележка двигается нормально, но не написали в каком треде она обсчитывается. Возможно на однопроцессорной машине тред в котором нет засыпания гоняет какие-то вычисления в цикле и не дает остальным тредам поработать.

Comment: Позиция тележки высчитывается в ThreadKeyLis extends Thread. Да, в нем есть метод run() с пустым while(true){} без Thread.sleep(), а так же 3 вложенных класcа типа Listener (2 mouse и 1 Keyboard). Я тоже подумал что дело в этом, поэтому добавил в цикл Thread.sleep(1000). Полет мяча стал действительно более плавным, однако только на 2-х ядерных ПК (пробовал на 3-х разных ПК с 2-мя ядрами). На одноядерном проблема осталась, хотя частота появления этого бага уменьшилась.